# Simple proof for convexity of a real valued matrix function

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization

I am looking for a simple and short proof showing that $X \to \|X X^\top\|_F^2$ is a convex function where $\|\cdot\|_F$ is the Frobenius norm. I have one proof by showing that the derivative is monotone but it is quite heavy. I expect that there are simple arguments showing this.

Answer (score 6):

Write $\|XX^\top\|_F^2=g(f(X))$, where $f(X)=\|X\|_4$ is the [Schatten 4-norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schatten_norm) and $g(t)=t^4$. Since $g$ is increasing on the range of $f$, convexity follows from [this answer on MathSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/287725/442087).